# Remove All Characters After First Character

Tags: python

Say I have the string:

```
fame = "John"
lname = "Doe"
```

What I want to do is make it so I can take the lname and make it so that everything after the first character is deleted, so I can abbreviate the last name. The output would be:

```
fullname = "John D."
```

I am not experienced with Python, so I can't find anything on this, because I don't know what this is really called.

Thanks!

Comment: Both are strings which are again arrays of sort. So you can access characters based on the index which you can concatenate later.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> fname = "John"
>>> lname = "Doe"
>>> fullname = '{0} {1}.'.format(fname, lname[0])
>>> fullname
'John D.'
```

Comment: Better yet: keep the formatting in the format string: `'{0} {1[0]}.'.format('John', 'Doe')`

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, you can call characters in strings by index. So The first character is index 0, the second is 1, and so on. So...

```
fullname = fname + " " + lname[0] + "."
```

or, a bit more pythonic:

```
fullname = "%s %s."%(fname, lname[0])
```

Python has some pretty good documentation. Read this to learn how to use strings in python: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html

----Edit----

It has come to my attention that using % notation is not a good idea in recent versions of Python. I'm guessing this is to help programmers avoid injection attacks. So, like other people have already said, it's best to use something like:

```
fullname = "{0} {1}.".format(fname, lname[0])
```

or

```
fullname = "{0} {1[0]}".format(fname, lname)
```

The Python documentation I provided earlier explains this too. Obviously, I can't take credit for the code in this edit.

Comment: Use of the `%` syntax is discouraged (if you're on a reasonably recent Python installation) - use `.format()` instead.

Comment: I was not aware of that. When I was learning Python that was the way I was taught to format strings. I will look into that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following sample code from the Python REPL is an example of how to accomplish what you want. You can index an element or elements of a string, like `lname[0]`, and concatenate sub-strings with '+'.

```
>>> fame = "John"
>>> lname = "Doe"  
>>> fullname = fame + " " + lname[0] + '.'
>>> fullname
'John D.'
```

Comment: While not wrong, this addition syntax is not best practice.  String formatting is much preferred.